# VHDL File IO, write to specific line number

Tags: vhdl

Is there a VHDL function that can write data to a specific line of a text file, without modifying the other lines?

This is for simulation needs, of course.

Comment: Here is a duplicate from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184087/how-to-read-from-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-vhdl

Comment: note that the main problem here isn't even VHDL. Files simply don't work as "collection of lines", they're a "sequence of bytes", and you could only replace bytes, not "change" a line in the middle, no matter which programming language you choose. So, copy all lines up to the line you want to modify from an input to an output file, write your modified line, copy the rest of the input file to the output file. Yes, that's what everyone else has to do, too.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The VHDL problem is that it doesn't even have a "seeking" capability, which is in general supported by files.

Comment: The missing functionality will be added in VHDL-2018 which is currently in ballot phase at IEEE working group P1076. First vendors are already supporting a subset of VHDL-2018. You can write to FAE and request more features / change priority on features by user requests.

Comment: And if the file initially has fewer than 15 lines, that's another case to handle in your code... Or if the file is temporarily locked for writes... Or owned by another user.. or invalid path... You might be better off piping commands to sed or awk or vim, and let an existing text editor handle all the various special cases. So now the problem becomes "sed command to replace line 15". Or you could try to refactor the problem to allow appending data instead of inserting it into an existing file.

Comment: [sed] replace line based on line number --   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708576/replace-line-based-on-line-number